# Shake Icons in Android as iPhone on Long Press

Tags: android, animation

I'm implementing an App where I want to shake the icons as in iPhone occurs.

How can I implement the same?

I have attached the code of my animation here. Please suggest me any solution. I have tried the soln that is already specified on the stack overflow but its not working in my case. And this class is a non-activity class in which this animation set is written.

```
protected void animateDragged(){
    View v = getChildAt(dragged);
    int x = getCoorFromIndex(dragged).x + childSize / 2, y = getCoorFromIndex(dragged).y + childSize / 2;
    int l = x - (3 * childSize / 4), t = y - (3 * childSize / 4);
    v.layout(l, t, l + (childSize * 3 / 2), t + (childSize * 3 / 2));
    AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(.667f, 1, .667f, 1, childSize * 3 / 4, childSize * 3 / 4);
    scale.setDuration(animT);
    AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1, .5f);
    alpha.setDuration(animT);

    animSet.addAnimation(scale);
    animSet.addAnimation(alpha);
    animSet.setFillEnabled(true);
    animSet.setFillAfter(true);

    v.clearAnimation();
    v.startAnimation(animSet);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be you can make `shake.xml` in `anim` folder.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromDegrees="-5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="5" />
```

Now use it in your method `animateDragged()` as

```
Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.shake);
v.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Its not working bro.
The method loadAnimation(Context, int) in the type AnimationUtils is not applicable for the arguments (DraggableGridView, int)

Comment: Thanks, I made my way out. Thanks

Comment: @GauravArora Could you please explain, How did you solve your problem. I am curious to learn and understand.

Answer (score 2):

You may also make **different random animations** for each view programatically. Just use code snippet below **in the loop** for each of your icons

```
        float px = ((float) Math.random() * .5f);
        float py = ((float) Math.random() * .5f);

        RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation((float) Math.PI / 2 * -1.f, (float) Math.PI / 2,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .25f + px,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .25f + py);
        anim.setDuration((long) (80. + (Math.random() * 50.)));
        anim.setRepeatCount(RotateAnimation.INFINITE);
        anim.setRepeatMode(RotateAnimation.REVERSE);

        v.startAnimation(anim);
```